# Drawing reference lines in LineChart using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the MPAndroidChart library. How to draw reference lines in LineChart? I would like to draw temperatures changes in time and additionally two horizontal lines with min&max acceptable temperatures.

Answer (score 3):

I found it. Author of the library called this mechanism as `LimitLine`. The example LineChartActivity1 shows the usage.

Here is an example of how to use it (in a `LineChart`):

```
LineData ld = new LineData(...);

LimitLine ll = new LimitLine(140f); // set where the line should be drawn
ll.setLineColor(Color.RED);
ll.setLineWidth(4f);
// .. and more styling options

ld.addLimitLine(ll);
```

Answer (score 3):

In newer version (at least >=2.2.3), you need to do:

```
private void setupGraph() {
    getXAxis().addLimitLine(getLimitLineAt(yValues.get(4).getXIndex()));
    getXAxis().addLimitLine(getLimitLineAt(yValues.get(3).getXIndex()));

    setData(lineData);
}

@NonNull private LimitLine getLimitLineAt(int xIndex) {
    LimitLine ll = new LimitLine(xIndex); // set where the line should be drawn
    ll.setLineColor(Color.BLACK);
    ll.setLineWidth(1);
    ll.setLabel("Banner Period");
    return ll;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a horizontal line:

```
val limitLine = LimitLine(y)
lineChart.axisLeft.addLimitLine(limitLine)
```

For a vertical line:

```
val limitLine = LimitLine(x)
lineChart.xAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
```